# Adding foreign key (Lquidbase)

Tags: java, database

I am trying to add a foreign key that would refer to a primary key in another table and that primary key would be in a column  user_id but for some reason i am getting Grammar exception

```
 <changeSet id="add-export_users-table" author="artjom.prozorov">
    <preConditions>
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="export_users"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createSequence sequenceName="export_users_id_seq"/>
    <createTable tableName="export_users">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT"/>
        <column name="user_id"/>
    </createTable>
    <addNotNullConstraint tableName="export_users" columnName="id"/>
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="export_users" columnNames="id"/>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="export_users"  baseColumnNames="user_id" constraintName="export_users_fk"
                             referencedTableName="users"
                             referencedColumnNames="user_id"/>



  Export class 
       @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity userEntity;

UserEntity class 
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq", sequenceName = "public.user_id_seq", allocationSize = 0)
    private Long id;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the column type is mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="export_users"
    baseColumnNames="user_id"
    constraintName="export_users_fk"
    referencedTableName="users"
    referencedColumnNames="user_id"/>
```

Assumes the ID of the `users` table is `user_id` but as I don't see any annotation at your `UserEntity @Id` I assume its ID is rather simply called `id`.

Comment: ahh you right, i were blind there , thank you for you assistance buddy, much appreciated